# Dynamics crm - including other columns in product lookup search > is it possible?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, product, lookup

I have customized my product lookup view to include `manufacturer` which is a new field however when typing into the search box it will not look in this column for matches.

Is it possible to include additional columns added to the view to be included in the search? if not the view, is there anywhere i can add this field to be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Views for your Product Entity, and edit the Quick Find view.  From there you can add additional columns to search.  [Here is a blog post on doing it in CRM 4.0](http://dynamicscare.com/blog/utilizing-the-quick-find-view-to-manipulate-the-account-search-functionality-in-crm-40/), luckily it hasn't changed much.

Comment: thanks so much! this worked a charm! Ive only been in the CRM scene for 6 months so still a massive learning curve for me. Any tips?

Comment: Whatever you don't know, google it, if you can't figure it out, Stackoverflow it.